# How to check if Wifi-Direct connection exists?

Tags: android, connectivity, wifi-direct

I want to update my android-app (2.3.3) which uses the smartphone's sensor-data  to stream via
WIFI to a remote-computer. Lately I have received many emails from people who tell me that they can't use the app for WIFI-direct connections.

The code in question reads:

```
private boolean isOnWifi() {
    ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return conman.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

As you can see, the function returns false if conman doesnot "find"  a WIFI-connection.
In WIFI-Direct mode the last line retunrs false even though there is a wifi-direct-connection.(it should return true)

I set the function to return true in all cases et voila the stream works fine.

So basically I need some input how to implement the function (Android 2.3.3)
isonWifi() in a way that it returns both true if there is a regular WIFI-connection
AND/OR there is Wifi-Direct-connection.

Anny ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: try pinging some adress known to be available quite a lot, like google.com. if you get a resultcode == 200, there is internet.

Comment: the app doesnt need internet, so this is not a solution